# Java Spring MongoDB Delete

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I am using Java Spring MongoDB API. When I use the MongoTemplate and try to delete an object, it does not delete. I am using Spring 3.0.6.REALEASE. My code can be seen below:

beans.xml

```
<mongo:mongo host=“localhost“ port=“27017“/>

<mongo:db-factory dbname=“database5“ mongo-ref=“mongo“/>

<bean id=“mongoTemplate“ class=“org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate“>
<constructor-arg name=“mongoDbFactory“ ref=“mongoDbFactory“/>
</bean>

@Document
public class Student {

@Id
private String id;
@Field
private int age;

public Student(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

// getters and setters
}
```

I get the mongoTemplate through ApplicationContext and invoke remove method passing in the Student object filled by Id and age but it doesn' delete.

Any ideas?

```
Student student = new Student(5);
student.setId(“ “);
mongoTemplate.remove(student);
```

Where Id is an Id filled in.

No exceptions, but when finding this Id it still exists.

Comment: Where's the code for the actual deletion?

Comment: can you provide your actual code that does a delete - and also how it fails?  Do you just get no error and the document stays or do you get an error, or something else?

Comment: @RajivJain did you resolve your problem?

Comment: Please see edit above. No exceptions still exist in MongoDB as I can find this through the Java Spring code.

Answer (score 7):

Try specifying the collection name:

```
mongoTemplate.remove(student, "student");
```

Or you can also try to remove it using a query:

```
mongoTemplate.remove(new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(student.getId())), Student.class);
```

Also, to get more information of what's happening, use getLastError:

```
System.out.println(mongoTemplate.getDb().getLastError());
```

If the object gets removed, you'll see n:1 like this:

```
{ "serverUsed" : "vmd-eumongoacct-002/172.20.15.15:27017" , **"n" : 1** , "lastOp" : { "$ts" : 1365111932 , "$inc" : 1} , "connectionId" : 305018 , "err" :  null  , "ok" : 1.0}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try following

1) Make sure you are using annotation classes from spring data only. Since, you did not provide full code I can't  see your imports.

```
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.Document
```

2) Try saving the object first and delete the same object. If this test works then your delete also would work.

```
mongoTemplate.save(userObj);
System.out.println("saved user id:"+userObj.getId());
mongoTemplate.remove(userObj);
```